# Android : Google Play Console : New : Update countries list of existing application

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Android : Google Play Console : New : How to Update countries list of existing application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

play console> select your app> production >countries/ regions> you will find two options (add countries /regions)(remove countries/regions)